# Cumulative distribution function of dependent variables

Tags: conditional-expectation, independence

I have measured packet delays on several different radio channels $c_1, c_2, c_3$ and got three streams of delay data:

$d_{11}, d_{12}, d_{13}, \dots$

$d_{21}, d_{22}, d_{23}, \dots$

$d_{31}, d_{32}, d_{33}, \dots$

These measurements have been fitted to probability distribution functions $PDF_1, PDF_2, PDF_3$.

The probability that the delay of a packet on channel $c_i$ is unacceptably high, i.e. above some scalar constraint $A$ is given by:

$P(d_i > A) = 1 - CDF_i(A)$.

I want to calculate the probability that the delay on *all* channels is above that constraint; in other words, that the packet isn't received with acceptable delay on none of the channels.

The answer is simple if the random variables are independent:
$$
P(d_1 > A \wedge d_2 > A \wedge d_3 > A) \\
 = P(d_1 > A) \cdot P(d_2 > A) \cdot P(d_3 > A) \\
 = \prod_{i=1}^{3} (1 - CDF_i(A))
$$

However, in practice the radio channels are not independent. For example, the Pearson's correlation of the delays on the different channels is quite high.

How to take into account that dependence when calculating the cumulative probability?